# Compass Vertical Rythm For Non Text Elements

Tags: sass, workflow, compass

In these days I jumped into compass and i can say I really love it. By the way, I come up with some questions about a proper workflow that fits my needs. Let's have an example:

[my grid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1GQd.jpg)

As you can see i setup a pretty straightforward grid (5px since the whole vertical rhythm is based on a 25px baseline grid). I would like to know in which way i can fit non text elements ( as containers and images ) to the baseline taking advantage of built in compass mixins ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution on my own. I share it with you, maybe it can be useful for someone or, better, you can help me to improve it.

Taking the example above.

Let's set our baseline 25px with:

```
@import "compass/typography/vertical_rhythm";

$base-font-size: 16px;
$base-line-height: 5px;

@include establish-baseline;

html {@include adjust-leading-to(5);}
```

In this way we subdivide our baseline in subunits (1/5 in this case) to have more freedom in composition.

Now we can play with two compass elements to adjust white space accordingly with our design:

```
.inner-header {
    @include leader(3);
    @include trailer(2);
}
```

leader permit to control leading space by a number of baseline's lines ( in this case leading space will be of 3 lines, 15px )

trailer do the same for trailing space.

I don't think this is the most elegant solution around but for now it works !

UPDATE

I find out that the best way to deal with white space is the following shorthand mixin

```
rhythm-padding($padding-leader, $padding-trailer, $font-size)
```